# How do you assign the value of a table row to a checkbox in React?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, checkbox

I'm a fairly new developer so my apologies if this is a simple question. I've been googling for an entire day and have yet to find an answer so I figured I'd come the hive mind of stackOverflow :). I'm trying to migrate an Angular app to a React app and I can't figure out how to interpret the Angular code for this specific action into React. I have SOME experience with React and absolutely none with Angular.

Essentially what's happening is, a user searches something which hits a DB, and once the results come back in, they "map" into a table and you can click a checkbox next to each of them and enable/disable something.. for the purpose of this question, we'll say it enables/disables comments. The Angular code is as follows

The controller:

```
$scope.enableComments = function() {
    var checkedItems = document.getElementsByName("checkbox-comments");
    var comments = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
        if (checkedItems[i].checked) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(checkedItems[i].value);
            obj.Attributes = obj.Attributes | ATTRIBUTES.COMMENTS
            comments.push(obj)
        }
    }
```

The form.html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="res in resources | orderBy: predicate:reverse">
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-comments" value="{{res}}">
   </td>
... some other <td>'s
```

There is then code that sends this update to an API which updates the comments attribute in the DB, but I know how to implement that code. I've tried implementing the controller part of this code in the exact same way in React and it does not work.

I need to somehow attach each search result row (which I do track in React state as searchResult and this is what I map out in my React code) to each checkbox next to it, and as they're checked, add them to an empty array that I can then pass as a parameter to the API call.

As for my React code currently, the "controller" is currently the same (even though it doesn't work) but my JSX is as follows:

```
                  <tbody>
                    {props.data.searchResult.map(el => { 
// I take the search results which are stored in state and map them to a table. The table headers are in code that I didn't include here
                      return (
                        <tr key={el.example}>
                          <td>
                            <input 
                              type="checkbox" 
                              name="streams-checkbox" 
                              value={props.data.searchResult} 
                 // I don't think this ^^^ makes sense because searchResult is an array 
                    of objects..
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>{el.example1}</td>
                          <td>{el.example2}</td>
                          <td>{el.example3}</td>
                          <td>{el.example4}</td>
```

Maybe my value is wrong? Because the search result would be an array of objects.. do I need an onChange? I don't know why I can't figure this out but it's driving me crazy. Thanks in advance for any guidance and I hope I explained this well enough!
[The App UI showing the table (with just example data) and the checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG2wm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a checkbox use:

```
<input type='checkbox' value={el.example}/>
```

`value={props.data.searchResult}` is your issue because not only should you be using `checked` but you also can't assign an array to a single value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! SearchResult is an array though because map is an array method. In this case, it is mapping an array of objects, hence the `el.example` syntax. The issue is, I need each object that's being mapped, to be the value of each checkbox next to it. So if I check a box, I'm saying "I want everything else that's in this table row, to be the value of this check box. I want to 'select' this row"

Comment: You're correct, I wasn't thinking.  Updated answer.  I'm not sure what you mean but either you can directly test for a "true" boolean in your data for that correlating checkbox and assign it, or you can apply any logic you want to check it.

Comment: No worries! It happens to the best of us. Honestly, I don't think I even really know how to explain what I'm doing lol. I just know that it works in the old Angular UI but I absolutely cannot get it to work in React haha

Comment: Updated answer... I remember why I was focused on the array, it's because of assigning the array to value which is not correct, you have to use the map item 'el' that you've created to assign that value.

Comment: Okay so it's interesting that you said this because I tried assigning value={el} and when I console.log it out, it just prints out [object Object].. it's very weird! Do I need an onChange or something for the checkbox?

Comment: I can, however, map the index as well and set the index of the elements as the value of the checkboxes (those console.log out just fine) but then I don't know how to associate the index with the elements I'm mapping out

Comment: You can't just assign el to checkbox, el is an object.  You're looping over searchResult and el is each item in that array.  You need something like el.value or el.checkbox or el.whatever to get the "true" value for checkbox.

Comment: Okay, yes, that makes sense.. but then how the heck did they do it in the Angular code? If you look at the Angular code above, they have value-{{ res }} and that res is 'resources' and I've console logged out those resources and they're the same as when I console log out the search results in React.. it's objects with info in them.

Comment: I don't know angular code, but ````ng-repeat="res in resources"```` likely means it's a loop and ````res```` is equivalent to ````el````, it's taking each item from resources and assigning it to res.  And then, unless there's some incredibly special thing happening,  ````value="{{res}}">```` can only be possible if that res is not an object.  The ````value```` needs to be something like el.name and the ````checked```` property needs to be checked if the el.name is present in some other "values" field.

Comment: So in the Angular controller code, I console log out `cks`, I console log out `typeof(cks)` and I console log out `cks[i].value`. `cks` is a node list which makes sense if you look at the Angular controller, `typeof(cks)` comes back as 'object', and `cks[i].value` prints out each object and it's data. However, if I do this in the react code, the same console log of `cks[i].value`, simply prints out [object Object]

Comment: As I mentioned, I have no idea what angular does with it, but assigning an object to an input value is not possible in html or any browser, that's just a fact.  The value of the input has to be a string, so if you want to assign a value to it you'll need to use el.someString in react.  I'm also not sure why you're console logging "cks" or where that value is coming from because the array that angular is using is called "resources".

Comment: I was logging it out because `cks` represents the checkboxes and their values. Either way, I figured it out. lol. Thank you for indulging me though! This was a great conversation and I appreciate the time you put into it :)